# Queuable job - hitting Apex CPU limit

Tags: apex

I am using a batch job to process records and write it into a file in the finish method.This is failing for large data.
Apex CPU limit is hit by the code from the finish method. To counter this, I created an Apex Queuable job which does the job of writing the contents into a file.I am invoking this job from the finish method.
Apex CPU limits are still hit. How should this issue be solved? 
Any ideas, highly appreciated.
**Trying to explain again:**
My code is too long to be posted here. I have a batch class to go over a large number of records.  The information from the data collected in the execute method of the batch class is processed & the summary is written into a file in the finish method of the batch class. When the number of records is high, the data to process is also high thus exceeding CPU limit in the finish method where it is writing the processed information into a file.

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
   ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(new InvExtractWriteQueuable(mapOfBillInv));  
}
```

To overcome this, I have written a queuable job & calling from the finish method of the batch class. The queuable job is passed the data from the finish method of the batch job. The queuable job extracts the data and writes it into a file. I thought that coding in a  Queuable would save me from the Apex CPU limit, but I am getting the same error again in the Queuable class.

Comment: Please include, at the very least, the code of your queueable class. Knowing approximately how many records you're working with would also be helpful.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Is the CPU timeout occurring during the batch job or the queueable job?

Comment: Edited the post with more details.

Comment: Do you have an infinite loop when you write content to file?

Comment: No @Patlatus. It was failing with Apex CPU limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should look into optimizing your code on why it is consuming so much cpu time.. 
Alternatively If there no room for optimization then you can distribute the processing and implement job chaining.
I would distribute the processing in first batch class's batch chunks and make the each batch processing independent if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post how I progressed on the solution for someone who might come looking for it someday:
I first got 'Too many queueable jobs' error when I tried to have a loop to chunk the Queuable jobs.
So, what is not allowed as documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) is something like the following:

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    for(Integer i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
     System.enqueueJob(new InvExtractWriteQueuable1(map)); 
   }
}
```

This kind of invoking Queuable job in a loop is not allowed from any kind of asynchronous job: Batch, Queuable either from execute/finish methods 
So, invoking more than 1 Queuable job is not allowed.

What is allowed though is:

```
public class InvExtractWriteQueuable1 implements Queueable {
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        System.enqueueJob(new InvExtractWriteQueuable2(map)));
    }
}
public class InvExtractWriteQueuable2 implements Queueable {
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        System.enqueueJob(new InvExtractWriteQueuable1(map)));
    }
}
```

Caution must be exercised not to go in circles here and have logic to terminate the loop of calling alternate Queuable jobs when required.